# How to store webcam feed on server in realtime?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, recordrtc

I am simply trying to record the webcamera feed if the user, and store the data on server. Now I could wait till recording is done, generate the video file on client end and then upload it to server, but if the client disconnects during the upload process the entire video would be lost. In order to prevent that, I am sending blobs every 1 second to server and attempting to stitch them together in a video. This kind of works, but is not very reliable as sometimes there seems to be no video or corrupt video. My code is below:

I am using RecordRTC js on frontend with socketio and nodejs on the backend.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: true
            }).then(async function(stream) {
                    console.log('recording started');
                    recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                    recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder,
                    mimeType: 'video/webm',
                    timeSlice: 1000, // 1 second interval
                    ondataavailable: function(blob) {
                        socket.emit('store-video',{blob:blob, session:'{{ $sessionId }}'});
                        console.log('recording blob: ',blob.size);
                    }
                });
                recorder.startRecording();

                setTimeout(()=>{
                    recorder.stopRecording();
                    socket.emit('stop-video',{session:'{{ $sessionId }}'});
                    console.log('recording stopped');
                },20000);
            })
```

And on my server I am doing

```
//using: npm fs-blob-store
let ws = blobs.createWriteStream({
                key: d.session+'/video.webm'
            });
            socket.ws = ws; 
        ....
        ...
        socket.on('store-video', function(d){
            if(socket.ws && d.blob){
                console.log('recording data');
                socket.ws.write(d.blob);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's an example of corrupt video or no video?  These blobs aren't independent... you need to track the initialization data separately if you plan to play them separately.  But, if you want to decode them in-order, it should be fine if all the blobs make it there.

Comment: @Brad by no video I mean sometimes I end up with 0 bytes, as if the video data was overwritten. And by corrupt video I mean the video doesn't open in any player even though there seems to be data there.

Can you tell me how I can track initialization data?

Comment: You are also going to have issues with congestion. If you attempt to send more video then the connection supports it will fall behind (and who knows how much). I would really suggest doing something using the WebRTC media APIs or WebTransport. Pion WebRTC has https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/save-to-disk but you can use anything.